# Refresh MEN stack webpage without refreshing the entire page

Tags: javascript, ajax, express, azure-cosmosdb

I am creating a data analytics dashboard using the MEN stack. (express,node,ejs) However, I would like to display the real-time data that refreshes every 5 seconds WITHOUT refreshing the HTML page which I am doing so currently using the following scripts.

Everything works. But, it's kind of an eyesore to see the page refreshing all the time. Is there a way to use AJAX or something to refresh a particular DIV or PAGE?? I've tried different AJAX functions on different places but it doesn't work. Maybe am doing it the wrong way. Any advice?

```
async showTasksMain(req, res) {
const queryWeather = "SELECT * FROM c ORDER BY c.EventProcessedUtcTime desc"

const items = await this.taskDao.findweather(queryWeather); //Return variables
const tempdata = await this.taskDao.findtempdata(queryWeather);

res.render("index",{items:items, tempdata:tempdata});
}
```

```
async findweather(queryWeather) {
debug("Querying for items from the database");
if (!this.container) {
throw new Error("Collection is not initialized.");
}

const { result: results } = await this.container.items
.query(queryWeather)
.toArray();

var obj = results[0];
return obj;
}
```

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => taskList.showTasksMain(req, res).catch(next));
```

```
  <script type = "text/JavaScript">
        function AutoRefresh( t ) {
           setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
        }
  </script>

<body onload="JavaScript:AutoRefresh(30000)">;
```

Comment: FWIW, you can update data in real time without having to refresh the page.

Comment: I tried to console.log. the data gets updated. but it's not reflecting on the html view. Hmm..

Comment: use ajax long polling to get data and jquery to insert or update required div etc?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample javascript code to refresh partial page like some `div`

Suppose , you have menu like beloe:

```
ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
    <li><a href="products.html">Products</a>
</ul>
```

and you have content div like below:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

you can then write a code something like:

```
$("#menu li a").click(function(e) {
    // prevent from going to the page
    e.preventDefault();

    // get the href
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    $("#content").load(href, function() {
        // do something after content has been loaded
    });
});
```

You can refer **[Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)**

Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Hope it helps.